# Why does power (other conditions equal) decrease as the odds ratio increases above 2?

Tags: regression, logistic, simulation

I am simulating a logistic regression setting (P(Y=1|x).  Estimated proportion of patients with a poor feature at time zero is 40%. I am generating 1000 replications per scenario, sample size ranging from 100 to 200 by 10, for odds ratios ranging from 1.5 to 2.5 by 0.1.  I generate x (years) from Uniform~(2,6). Relative power increases appropriately for odds ratios from 1.5 to 2.0.  However, relative power decreases for odds ratios greater than 2.0. Does anyone have an explanation for this.

[image]

```
data t; 
b0=-0.405;`enter code here`
do or=1.5 to 2.5 by 0.1;
b1=log(or);
do ss=100 to 200 by 10;
    do rep=1 to 1000;
        do i=1 to ss;
        *years=6*ranuni(34958487);
        years=4*ranuni(34958487)+2;
        *years=1*rannor(34958487)+3;
        lp=b0 + b1*years;
        pi=exp(lp)/(1 + exp(lp));
        y=ranbin(45823765,1,pi);
        output;
        end;
    end;
end;
end;
run;

proc sort data=t; by b1 ss rep;run;
ods listing close;
ods select ParameterEstimates(persist);
ods output ParameterEstimates=Estimates;
proc logistic descending data=t;
by b1 ss rep;
model y=years;
run;
ods select all;
ods listing;

data reject; set estimates;
if variable="years";
rej=(probchisq<0.05);
or=exp(b1);
run;
proc sort data=reject; by or ss;run;
options pageno=1 pagesize=max;
proc freq data=reject;
by or;
tables ss*rej/ out=power;
title "Rejection Probability";
run;

data power; set power;
if rej=1;
rejprob=count/1000;
keep or ss rejprob;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to ceiling effects. Look at a plot of the success probabilities in some of your simulated data sets when $\beta_1$ is near the higher end of your range, $\log(2.4)$, vs. the lower end, $\log(1.6)$. Toward the higher end, far more of the predicted probabilities get near upper bound of 1. For example, when $\beta_1 = \log(1.6)$, around $15\%$ of predicted probabilities will be above $.95$; when $\beta_1 = \log(2.4)$, that is more like $50\%$. This dynamic makes it harder to determine the precise effect of the predictor, which is reflected in an increased standard error, and thus a smaller power. To get the expected results, you should fix the marginal probability, $P(Y=1)$, across simulations by adjusting $\beta_0$ appropriately.

Comment: I fixed b0 such that the probability of the event at time zero was 40% in all models.  I am confident your diagnosis is correct.  However,  I do not know how to fix the marginal probability, P(Y=1), across simulations by adjusting b0. Can you expand on this?  Thank you.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you could calculate $$ P(Y=1) = E_X (P(Y=1|X)) $$ as a function of $\beta_0, \beta_1$. Given the distribution of $X$, that would equal $$ f(\beta_0, \beta_1) = \frac{1}{4} \int_{2}^{6} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}} dx $$ I don't think you can do this analytically but, for a fixed value of $\beta_1$ and $P(Y=1)$, you can find the proper value of $\beta_0$ by numerically solving for a root of the equation $$f(\beta_0, \beta_1) - P(Y=1) $$